# Jetty HttpServletResponse can't be modified

Tags: firefox, audio, character-encoding, jetty, content-type

we want to use jPlayer, an HTML5 audio player with firefox in order to play .ogg files. We noticed that there are issues with HTML5 audio and firefox considering the MEME attribute in the HTTP response. In this case, our content-type resembles "audio/ogg;charset=UTF-8". We think that removing the charset encoding might result in firefox interpreting the file correctly.

Hence, I tried the following in my spring implementation:
response.setContentType("audio/ogg");
response.setCharacterEncoding("");

The first line should not set an encoding. Nevertheless, it's already present before in the response object (recognized this while debugging). The weird thing is: the second line doesn't change anything, the character encoding is not modified. This behavior is totally contradictory to the API description.

Reference: it does not work as described in sample #2 of this post: [Jetty Response with no Charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528014/jetty-response-with-no-charset)

I appreciate any ideas how-to fix the problem.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: **What version of Jetty?** _Please provide all relevant details in your SO questions. There are 3 major, and multiple minor versions of Jetty in wide-spread usage - it's almost impossible for us to verify your results unless we know what version you're talking about._

Comment: @Tim: you're totally right. We're working with Jetty 7.4.5 and SpringSource 2.9.1.RELEASE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*"Works for me..." (although you should set the char encoding to `null` rather than `""`)*

I wrote some sample code (below) and ran it against 7.4.5
I get the right content type being sent through.

I'm not sure what's going wrong for you - perhaps you could post some code.

My best guess is that you're trying to set the content-type after having already sent content. Since the content type is a header, you need to set it before any of the body gets committed.

```
public class JettyServer
{
    public static class OggServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            File file = new File("src/main/ogg/file.ogg");

            response.setContentType("audio/ogg");
            response.setCharacterEncoding(null);
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            int by;
            while ((by = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                response.getOutputStream().write(by);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
        handler.addServlet(OggServlet.class, "/audio");
        server.setHandler(handler);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will do anything different, but you could try bypassing the convenience method and calling setHeader method directly:

```
setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/ogg");
```

If you really are stumbling over some kind of bug in Jetty, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, but already tried that one -> same result. When only using this, the character encryption is automatically set to UTF-8. Just another remark: when I change the encoding in my web.xml file, it's also changed in the HTTP response (as it is supposed to), so it isn't set anywhere explicitly.